# Custom query in Cakephp and show in table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to make a custom query in cakephp, but is not working.
The page still loading and loading and loading, never show me the data. Also, I think I have an error when I want to show the data:

This is the function that I want to use in my TurnosController.php

```
 public function estadisticas()
{
    //$paisFK = $this -> Auth -> User()['paisFK'];
    //$this->paginate['contain'] = ['Canchas', 'Canchas.Complejos', 'Canchas.Complejos.Ciudades','Usuarios'];
    //$this->paginate['conditions'] = ['Usuarios.paisFK' => $paisFK, ];
    //$turnos = $this->paginate($this->Turnos);
    //$this->set(compact('turnos'));
    //$this->set('_serialize', ['turnos']);

    $turnostotales = $this->Turnos->query('SELECT c.nombre, c.idComplejo, t.canchaFK, count(*) AS cantidadTurnos FROM turno t inner join complejo c inner join ciudad cc inner join cancha ca inner join usuario u on t.canchaFK=ca.idCancha and c.idComplejo=ca.complejoFK and u.idUsuario=t.usuarioFK  WHERE u.esComplejo=0 and cc.paisFK="1" and u.paisFK="1"  and cc.idCiudad=c.ciudadFK and noAsistio=0 and fecha between "2016-07-01" and "2016-07-30" group by canchaFK ');
    $this->set('turnostotales',$turnostotales);

}
```

And in my view **estadisticas.ctp**
I have this part of code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('idComplejo', 'ID Complejo') ?></th>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('canchaFK', '# Cancha') ?></th>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('cantidadTurnos', 'Cantidad Turnos') ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?= __('Acciones') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($turnostotales as $turno): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= h($turno->idComplejo) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($turno->canchaFK) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($turno->cantidadTurnos) ?></td>
            <td class="actions">
                <?= $this->Html->link(__('Ver'), ['action' => 'view', $turno->idTurno]) ?>
                <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Eliminar'), ['action' => 'delete', $turno->idTurno], ['confirm' => __('Desea eliminar el turno de la cancha {0} asociado al complejo {1}?', $turno->cancha->nroCancha, $turno->cancha->complejo->nombre)]) ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this part:

```
<td><?= h($turno->idComplejo) ?></td>
<td><?= h($turno->canchaFK) ?></td>
<td><?= h($turno->cantidadTurnos) ?></td>
```

I wanna show the atributes of the SELECT clause of the query, but I'm not sure if is right make it like this.

So.. Someone can help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: which version of cake are you using? Since you are using a custom query instead of cake's ORM (which I recommend you switch to), try building it slowly until you find where the error lies. So first build your main select query, then start adding your joins and finally add your where conditions. Start from something that works and debug the output in your foreach loop.

Comment: @KonstantinosDaskalopoulos The query works perfect. Is not the problem que query. The version of Cake php is 3.0

Comment: How do you know that the query is fine if the page is loading forever? Have you run it in the database as raw mysql? Can you dump the results of the query at a log file and paste them here?

Comment: @KonstantinosDaskalopoulos  var_dump returns a list of data like this: { ["nombre"]=> string(13) "El Pasillo F5" ["idcomplejo"]=> string(2) "13" ["canchafk"]=> string(2) "19" ["cantidadturnos"]=> string(1) "7" } Now the rows are empty, not loading and loding like before. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819007/cakephp-3-x-show-me-empty-row-with-my-custom-query/38819052?noredirect=1#comment65005106_38819052