# Cakephp 3.x show me empty row with my custom query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I made a custom query in my cakephp 3.0, but when I wanna display the data in a table, the rows are empty. This is my function in controller:

```
public function estadisticas()
{
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $stmt = $conn->execute('SELECT c.nombre, c.idComplejo, t.canchaFK, count(*) AS cantidadTurnos FROM turno t inner join complejo c inner join ciudad cc inner join cancha ca inner join usuario u on t.canchaFK=ca.idCancha and c.idComplejo=ca.complejoFK and u.idUsuario=t.usuarioFK  WHERE u.esComplejo=0 and cc.paisFK="1" and u.paisFK="1"  and cc.idCiudad=c.ciudadFK and noAsistio=0 and fecha between "2016-07-01" and "2016-07-30" group by canchaFK');
    $turnostotales = $stmt ->fetchAll('assoc');

    $this->set('turnostotales',$turnostotales);


}
```

The query works perfect. Also, The page show me the table with 19 empty row (19 row is the result of the query).

This is the part of code where I display the data:

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('idComplejo', 'ID Complejo') ?></th>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('canchaFK', '# Cancha') ?></th>
            <th><?= $this->Paginator->sort('cantidadTurnos', 'Cantidad Turnos') ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($turnostotales as $turnostotale): ?>
        <tr>

            <td><?= h($turnostotale->idComplejo) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($turnostotale->canchaFK) ?></td>
            <td><?= h($turnostotale->cantidadTurnos) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed query format for anyone else reading:

```
SELECT     c.nombre, 
           c.idcomplejo, 
           t.canchafk, 
           Count(*) AS cantidadturnos 
FROM       turno t 
INNER JOIN complejo c 
INNER JOIN ciudad cc 
INNER JOIN cancha ca 
INNER JOIN usuario u 
ON         t.canchafk=ca.idcancha 
AND        c.idcomplejo=ca.complejofk 
AND        u.idusuario=t.usuariofk 
where      u.escomplejo=0 
AND        cc.paisfk="1" 
AND        u.paisfk="1" 
AND        cc.idciudad=c.ciudadfk 
AND        noasistio=0 
AND        fecha BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND        "2016-07-30" 
GROUP BY   canchafk
```

Looks like your query is broken. Try it in heidi/sql program of choice and fix it there.

Hows this:

```
SELECT     c.nombre, 
           c.idcomplejo, 
           t.canchafk, 
           Count(*) AS cantidadturnos 
FROM       turno t 
INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.idusuario = t.usuariofk
INNER JOIN cancha ca ON t.canchafk = ca.idcancha 
INNER JOIN complejo c ON c.idcomplejo = ca.complejofk 
INNER JOIN ciudad cc ON cc.idciudad=c.ciudadfk
WHERE      u.escomplejo=0 
AND        cc.paisfk="1" 
AND        u.paisfk="1" 
AND        noasistio=0 
AND        fecha BETWEEN "2016-07-01" AND        "2016-07-30" 
GROUP BY   canchafk
```

It looks like lots of your joins don't have ON clauses.

Comment: Your using INNER joins. Do you have data in every table? If you don't you want LEFT joins. Its best breaking down the query in SQL studio removing each join one at a time until you get data to find where the problem is. The cake code looks fine for query execution. I'm not sure on the view syntax.

Comment: Yes, I have data in every table. Also in phpmyadmin the same query show mit 19 rows with data in each column. But in cakephp, rows are empty

Comment: You have established a connection to this database earlier in the script and the user has select privileges on these tables? Also what happens if you var_dump($turnostotales) in the controller. Have you confirmed that its getting nothing out. Also check the php error logs for an issue.

Comment: $Kngsy var_dump returns a list of data like this:  { ["nombre"]=> string(13) "El Pasillo F5" ["idcomplejo"]=> string(2) "13" ["canchafk"]=> string(2) "19" ["cantidadturnos"]=> string(1) "7" }

Comment: I'm not an expert in cakephp but isnt the value you set an array not an object? So instead of <td><?= h($turnostotale->idComplejo) ?></td> it would be <td><?= $turnostotale['idComplejo'] ?></td>?